# How to redirect old pages to new pages

Tags: url-rewrite

What is the best way to redirect/rewrite url in Magento?

What we have are old page (urls) (not from a Magento system):

www.outdoorequipped.com/info/Asics

And to this url it needs to rewrite or redirected:

www.outdoorequipped.com/active/asics/

I tried many things, but it not works for us:

- I tried the URL Rewrite Management from Magento
- In htaccess I have

  Redirect 301 www.outdoorequipped.com/info/Puma https://www.outdoorequipped.com/

and I tried

```
RewriteRule https://www.outdoorequipped.com/info/Asics https://www.outdoorequipped.com/active/asics [r=301,nc]
```

But nothing is working.

What I can check and do else?

Comment: Redirect 301 http://domain.com/category/sub_category.html http://domain.com/sub_category.html try your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I figured out and finally with lines like this:

```
Redirect permanent /info/Asics /active/asics
```

It works now.